# How to verify a public key in string/byte[] format against certificates in bks store

Tags: android, encryption, certificate, public-key-encryption, public-key

I want to verify if a certificate with a certain public key exits in android keystore or not.I have key which is holded in a string.How do I verify if the corresponding certificate is present in keystore.
When checked the apis i found certificate.verify(mykey); is the only option.but mykey sholud be of type PublicKey and I have it in **string**.

**String is 0r1wxn7wIXJuS/hDnDvectD2VTmel9akk8awIWAXIRo= .....this is a hash of public key..i have to return back the certficate corresponding to this key.
Can anyone help me ?**

Can anyone help me ?

Regards
kozlov

Comment: Just to verify: are you sure you need to do that and not actually verify the server the ordinary way using keystores? I just can not think of a use case in which you will need to do such kind of comparison.

Comment: What does it look like as a String? Can you edit your question and add the actual String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
KeyStore store = ... ;
byte[] target = ... ; // Base-64 decode your string.
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
Enumeration<String> aliases = store.aliases();
while(aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
  String alias = aliases.nextElement();
  Certificate c = store.getCertificate(alias);
  if (c == null)
    continue;
  PublicKey pub = c.getPublicKey();
  byte[] hash = digest.digest(pub.getEncoded());
  if (MessageDigest.isEqual(hash, target)) {
    // Certificate "c" is a match.
  }
}
```